# Flash: Improve performance by “removing scaling” on vector graphics?

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript, graphics, adobe

I have a legacy flash game that is being up-rezed (800x600 -> 1024x768). I can easily scale the stage but am concerned about performance.  Converting everything to bitmaps would be a huge footprint I want to avoid.

My question is this-- Would it make any difference if I went to the trouble to scale the vector art so they effectively had a net zero transform?  Or would that make any difference.  Doesn't flash have to multiply the vector coordinates by a transform anyway or is it highly optimized for "no scaling"?

Comment: I'm not sure (so I make this a comment rather than an answer) it would make any difference if you would scale the art, I think not much, since vector drawing is a strong point of Flash, but one thing that effects performance a lot is pure size of the area that is redrawn each frame, so generally, animating a 1024x768 area is a lot heavier than animating a 800x600 area, as far as pure pixel pushing goes.

Answer (score 0):

Scale does not affect vector graphics size in memory only process time, because they use a transform matrix already in place even if its empty or no. You would see no difference what so ever. Bitmaps would have to be rescalled and rerendered. If you change their scale without re printing them out, it wont change the size but the quality will be diminished depanding on how much you scale and additional cpu power will be diverted.

Best way to deal with this is to resize assets inside of flash's ide OR our easy way out would be a matrix transform on a bitmap.draw of your final scene considering you have somethig like a camera.

Hope this helps.